# Find negative cycles in a directed edge-weighted graph using JGrapht

Tags: java, directed-graph, jgrapht

Is it possible to use JGrapht to find negative cycles in a directed edge-weighted graph?  I've looked through the Javadocs and found I can use a `CycleDetector` to detect cycles, but not specifically negative cycles. CycleDetector finds cycles, but you can't tell if they're negative or not without somehow exploring them some other way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use  the `BellmanFordShortestPath`, but it will not find the loop if you look for a path from one vertex to itself, because every vertex is implicitly connected to itself with a weight `0`.

```
DefaultDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> directedGraph = new DefaultDirectedWeightedGraph<>(DefaultWeightedEdge.class);

...

BellmanFordShortestPath<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> algorithm = new BellmanFordShortestPath(graph);

GraphPath<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> path = algorithm.getPath(node1, node1);

int length = path.getLength(); // returns 0
double weight = path.getWeight(); // returns 0.0
```

The best I can find are the algorithms in `org.jgrapht.alg.cycle`, which give you all cycles and then you have to calculate the total weight of the path around the cycle.

```
private boolean hasNegativeLoop(DefaultDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> graph){
    SzwarcfiterLauerSimpleCycles<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> cycleDetector = new SzwarcfiterLauerSimpleCycles<>(graph);

    List<List<String>> cycles = cycleDetector.findSimpleCycles();

    for (List<String> cycle : cycles){
        double cycleWeight = getCycleWeight(graph, cycle);

        if(cycleWeight < 0) return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private double getCycleWeight(DefaultDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> graph, List<String> cycle) {
    double totalWeight = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < cycle.size(); i++){
        double weight = graph.getEdgeWeight(graph.getEdge(cycle.get(i-1), cycle.get(i)));

        totalWeight += weight;
    }

    double weightBackToStart = graph.getEdgeWeight(graph.getEdge(cycle.get(cycle.size()-1), cycle.get(0)));

    return totalWeight + weightBackToStart;
}
```

This is way more inefficient comparing to Bellman Ford negative cycle detection, but could serve as a reference for your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In general you could use `BellmanFordShortestPath`to check for negative cycles in a graph, although the non-existence of a shortest path only tells you whether at least one negative cycle exists. I haven't had a proper look at the `BellmanFordShortestPath` implementation in JgraphT, so I can't provide you with code for that.

Other than that, there is a neat paper linked in https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6919/getting-negative-cycle-using-bellman-ford. 
A working link to the paper should be:

https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Negative-Weight-Cycle-Algorithms-Huang/dc1391024d74f736aa7a9c24191a35e822589516/pdf

So if all else fails, you could at least implement a working algorithm yourself, using a JgraphT graph like `DefaultDirectedWeightedGraph`

Comment: I already have an implementation of Bellman-Ford that I wrote for a course I'm taking.  But I wanted to generate some random graphs and compare the results of my implementation with some other implementation capable of detecting negative cycles specifically.  For this purpose, I figured I could either use someone else's implementation of Bellman-Ford, or write some non-Bellman-Ford alternative myself.